# issue with usage of css steps

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to have a 5 steps animation where, the steps should be :

1. top: 0rem;
2. top: -2rem;
3. top: -4rem;
4. top: -6rem;
5. top: -8rem;

But I can't do it. Everything I tried ended up with "top" values somewhat in between.

You can see this in motion there : http://jsfiddle.net/ax6hugvd/

```
.marQuee.T5 > DIV {
    animation: marquee_t5 25s steps(5, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee_t5 {
    to {
        top: -8rem;
    }
}
```

With samples going from 1 to 5 steps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/f4autmf7/

You have to take the end value, multiply it by ([number of steps] + 1) then divide it by [number of steps].

```
@keyframes marquee_t2 {
    100% {
        top: calc(-2rem * 3 / 2)
    }
}

@keyframes marquee_t3 {
    to {
        top: calc(-4rem * 4 / 3);
    }
}

@keyframes marquee_t4 {
    to {
        top: calc(-6rem * 5 / 4);
    }
}

@keyframes marquee_t5 {
    to {
        top: calc(-8rem * 6 / 5);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee_t2 {
    100% {
        top: calc(-2rem * 3 / 2);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee_t3 {
    to {
        top: calc(-4rem * 4 / 3);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee_t4 {
    to {
        top: calc(-6rem * 5 / 4);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee_t5 {
    to {
        top: calc(-8rem * 6 / 5);
    }
}
```